# What will happen if I use async/await with the function that returns nothing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, android-youtube-api

First of all, I am a beginner at javascript, especially in async/await/promise.

I want to use `seekTo()` method in the video library(react-native-youtube) synchronously. In [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), it said Await Expression need Promise or some value. Is it possible to use the `seekTo()` method even if it returns nothing?

```js
initVideo = async () => {
  await this._youTubeRef && this._youTubeRef.seekTo(startTime);
  this.setState({
    isPlaying: true
  });
}
```

If someone knows well about the react-native-youtube library, please advise me how to set endTime of the video to section playback.

Comment: Async functions essentially always return a promise even if when resolved there's nothing contained within the promise so awaiting for a promise should work regardless of what the promise resolves to.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @apokryfos !

Comment: The documentation doesn't say that seekTo returns a promise. Why is await needed?

Comment: @estus I just want to set a playtime section for the video. The seekTo() method execute some actions after called and it would spend a few seconds. Although I didn't mention on my question, I need to call setTimeout() after seekTo() for section playback.

Answer (score 5):

1. If a function (not async) does not explicitly return a value, then it returns `undefined` at the end of the function
2. You can use such "no return" functions just fine in an async context - they just return a Promise that resolves to undefined
3. Although I haven't worked with the library you mention, always keep in mind that `await x` is an expression, not a statement. So, if .seekTo is async, what you want is:

`&& await this._youTubeRef.seekTo(startTime);`

Comment: Mostly correct, but since the function is async, it always returns a promise. If you don't specify a return value, the function will return a promise that resolves to `undefined`.

Comment: Thx, fixed that